# How to pre-enter a user input() in Python?

Tags: python

I am interacting with a 3rd party program that will request 2 user inputs to start running a process. I know what they are going to be and want to preempt them, so that I don't need to enter them every single time.

```
predict_user_input_1 = 'variable1...'
predict_user_input_2 = 'variable2...'
3rdParty.start()        #this will ask for 2 user inputs
```

Seeing as I don't have access to this process is there any way that I can queue up data for  input()  so that I don't need to type it out?

Another way to view this question would be if I had code:

```
var1 = 'var....'
var2 = 'othervar.....'

SOLUTION HERE

examplefunc()

def examplefunc:
   ex1 = input()
   ex2 = input()
```

Is there anything that will let would allow you to queue input() inside the function from outside the function.

Comment: this question belongs in Stackoverflow, and not in softwareengineering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 3rd party code is also in Python, you can simply patch the input function before you invoke the 3rd party code.

```py
def third_party():
    a = input()
    b = input()
    print(a, b)

def my_code():
    # backup the input function
    original_input = __builtins__.input
    # patch the input function
    counter = 0
    input_queue = ['first automatic input', 'another one']
    def my_custom_input(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal counter
        if counter < len(input_queue):
            counter += 1
            return input_queue[counter - 1]
        else:
            return original_input(*args, **kwargs)

    __builtins__.input = my_custom_input
    
    # invoke the 3rd party
    try:
        third_party()
    finally:
        # restore the input function
        __builtins__.input = original_input

my_code()
```

https://ideone.com/xVXHZl

Comment: One thing I forgot - you need to wrap the call to the 3rd party in a try-catch, so that, even if it throws an exception, you're able to restore the input function. Updated the code in my answer